# SignalR WebSocket handshake: Sec-WebSocket-Accept header is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, signalr

SignalR 3-RC1 user on ASP.NET 5 RC1

Getting the following error when trying to get websocket going.

Using Chrome 50.0.2661.87

Headers are the following:

Request header:
Date:Fri, 29 Apr 2016 13:51:54 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Upgrade:websocket
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Response Header:
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie: ...ASP.NET cookie
DNT:1
Host: host.tld
Origin: http://host.tld
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:liIKiClt7Z057EwteJYJXQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87 Safari/537.36

Using Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server 1.0.0-rc1

Server Setup:
Windows Server 2012 R2
IIS 8.5

Anything I can do to get that fixed?

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, this thread has an answer that worked for me https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3691. Go to Windows Features > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features and enable Websocket Protocol. IIS reset and reload the page.

Comment: Yea I answered my own question on GitHub but not here hahahaha. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Hockey J commented, I had answered my question on GitHub but not here.

To remedy this problem:

1. click Start
2. type **turn windows**
3. click *Turn Windows Features On Or Off*
4. in the control panel window, navigate to *Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features*
5. enable *Websocket Protocol*

[image]

6. click Start
7. type **cmd**, right click *Command Prompt* and choose *Run as Administrator*
8. type **iisreset** into the command prompt
9. refresh the page in the browser

See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3691

Comment: Windows Features > *Internet Information Service* > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features. For windows server it differs: https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Comment: IIS appears to change the Sec-WebSocket-Key received for some strange reason. Have confirmed by manually logging the value of that header. It is not the same as the client sends it.

Answer (score 1):

The server's implementation is not good, but probably you can work around the issue by including `Sec-WebSocket-Key` HTTP header in your request. To comply with the specification, `Sec-WebSocket-Version` header and `Connection` header are needed, too. See [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for details.

Comment: The implementation is done directly in SignalR so it's the one sending out the headers and what not. I do not have control on what headers are sent. I opened an issue on their github, but I have yet to hear from them.

I believed it was something that I did not configure properly but from what I was reading, it wasn't the case, people were doing the workaround (in PHP)